# How to use multiple editors on one webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had created a code editor where you can view your code. Here is the code (Press Full Page):

```js
function openLanguage(evt, codeLanguage) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  let currentTab = document.querySelector('.tablinks.active');

  tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .tabcontent");
  tabcontent.forEach(content => content.style.display = "none");

  tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tab .tablinks");
  tablinks.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));

  if (currentTab != evt.currentTarget) {
    document.getElementById(codeLanguage).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {font-family: Arial;}

.codeOutput {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid;
border-right: 1px solid;
}

.result {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tabs {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tabs {
        display: flex;
    }
    .result {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tabcontent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeOutput">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="HTML" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

  <div id="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    Result
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Then I tried to add a second one but then I realized that the buttons of the second one open the tabs of the first one. Here is again an example with two editors (Press Full Page):

```js
function openLanguage(evt, codeLanguage) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  let currentTab = document.querySelector('.tablinks.active');

  tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .tabcontent");
  tabcontent.forEach(content => content.style.display = "none");

  tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tab .tablinks");
  tablinks.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));

  if (currentTab != evt.currentTarget) {
    document.getElementById(codeLanguage).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {font-family: Arial;}

.codeOutput {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid;
border-right: 1px solid;
}

.result {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tabs {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tabs {
        display: flex;
    }
    .result {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tabcontent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeOutput">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="HTML" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

  <div id="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    Result
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- Second Editor -->

<div class="codeOutput">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'HTML')">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'CSS')">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLanguage(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="HTML" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

  <div id="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    Result
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a different selector for each editor. Because the current query selector will always return the first editor section to you.

So that instead of:

```
tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tab .tablinks");
```

You can add an id for each section then use them in the selectors.

For example:

```
tablinksEditor1 = document.querySelectorAll("#editor1 .tab .tablinks");
tablinksEditor2 = document.querySelectorAll("#editor2 .tab .tablinks");
```

Comment: Hi Rami, isn't there a way to do it automatically? Because i will add many of them and i think it isnt the best way to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
class CodeOutput {
  containerId = "codeOutput";
  
  constructor(containerId){
    this.containerId = containerId;

    document.querySelectorAll("#"+this.containerId+" .tablinks").forEach(elm => {
      elm.addEventListener("click",this.openLanguage.bind(this));
    })
  }

  openLanguage(evt) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    let currentTab = document.querySelector("#"+this.containerId+' .tablinks.active');
    let codeLanguage = evt.target.getAttribute('target');

    tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll("#"+this.containerId+" .tabs .tabcontent");
    tabcontent.forEach(content => content.style.display = "none");

    tablinks = document.querySelectorAll("#"+this.containerId+" .tab .tablinks");
    tablinks.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));

    if (currentTab != evt.currentTarget) {
      document.querySelector("#"+this.containerId+" [tabTitle='"+codeLanguage+"']").style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}

new CodeOutput("codeOutput1");
new CodeOutput("codeOutput2");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {font-family: Arial;}

.codeOutput {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%)
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid;
border-right: 1px solid;
}

.result {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tabs {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tabs {
        display: flex;
    }
    .result {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tabcontent {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeOutput" id="codeOutput1">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" target="HTML">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" target="CSS">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" target="JavaScript">JavaScript</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div tabTitle="HTML" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

  <div tabTitle="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
  </div>

  <div tabTitle="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    Result
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- Second Editor -->

<div class="codeOutput" id="codeOutput2">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" target="HTML">HTML</button>
    <button class="tablinks" target="CSS">CSS</button>
    <button class="tablinks" target="JavaScript">JavaScript</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div tabTitle="HTML" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Some HTML Code</p>
    </div>

  <div tabTitle="CSS" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some CSS Code</p> 
  </div>

  <div tabTitle="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Some JS Code</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    Result
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```